# Undecidable language problems

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines

Let $L_1$ and $L_2$ be two undecidable languages.

1) Is it possible that $L_1 - L_2$ is regular and $L_1 - L_2 \neq \emptyset$ ?

Well I know that if I let $L_1 = L_2$ then $L_1 - L_2 = \emptyset$ which is obviously regular. In the case of this question however, I cannot set $L_1 = L_2$ if the outcome is an empty set, which makes me wonder what would $L_1 - L_2$ actually look like if they were not equal to each other.

2)  Is it possible that $L_1 \cup L_2$ is decidable and $L_1 \neq \neg L_2$ ?

This one is also tricky, since the obvious solution here would be to let $L_1 = \neg L_2 $.

Does anyone here have an idea as to how to finish my solutions here? I need to prove my solutions in both cases.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/66825/755, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2040900/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.